# Como listar as rotas no Laravel (Sem usar artisan)?

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, laravel-5

No `Laravel 4` eu sei como se lista todas as rotas através da linha de comando. Basta apenas fazer `php artisan routes`.

Porém, agora, eu tenho necessidade de fazer isso no código-fonte da minha aplicação.

Ou seja, necessito listar as rotas (num `foreach` por exemplo), capturando o nome das mesmas.

Tem como fazer isso? Gostaria de uma resposta que funcionasse tanto no `Laravel 4` e no `Laravel 5`.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/23673413/5165064 da uma olhada

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wallace, você pode fazer da seguinte forma:

```
foreach (Route::getRoutes() as $route) {
    var_dump($route->getUri());
}
```

A classe `Route` é um facade para a classe `Illuminate\Routing\Router` no `Laravel`.

Então, se você observar nessa classe, ela possui um método chamado `Router::getRoutes`. Esse método retornará uma instância de `Illuminate\Routting\RouteCollection`, que é uma coleção de rotas (`Illuminate\Routing\Route` não confundir com `Router`) que você adicionou no `Laravel`.

Se você quer transformar o objeto da classe `RouteCollection` em um `array`, basta chamar novamente o método `getRoutes` (porém dessa vez, esse método é de `RouteCollection` e não de `Router`).

Assim:

```
var_dump(Route::getRoutes()->getRoutes());
```

Você também poderá capturar o nome da rota através do método `Illuminate\Routing\Route::getName()`.

Assim:

```
foreach (Route::getRoutes() as $route) {
    var_dump($route->getName());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Complementando a resposta do amigo acima segue o código:

**Arquivo** /routes/web.php

```
Route::get('/rotas', 'TesteController@index');
```

**Arquivo** /app/Http/Controlers/TesteController.php

```
public function index()
{
    return view("rotas", [
       'resource' => Route::getRoutes()->getRoutes()
    ]);
}
```

**Arquivo** /resources/views/rotas.blade.php

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport"
          content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-WskhaSGFgHYWDcbwN70/dfYBj47jz9qbsMId/iRN3ewGhXQFZCSftd1LZCfmhktB" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <title>Rotas API</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
    <table class="table table-striped">
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <td>URL</td>
            <td>MÉTHODO</td>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        @foreach($resource as $rs)
            <tr>
                <td>{{$rs->uri}}</td>
                <td>{{$rs->methods[0]}}</td>
            </tr>
        @endforeach
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```